# Swift Core Data Insert doesn't fail, but doesn't get inserted

Tags: swift, core-data

I am returning JSON from a remote server using the Result Type in Swift 5.

I've tried all kinds of things, but it just won't save. Any help would go a long way.

The data is returning from the server just fine. URLSession.shared.jsonDecodableTask is a snippet I found on SO.

newData has all the correct values.

My code looks as follows:

```
URLSession.shared.jsonDecodableTask(with: urlComponents.url!) { (result: Result<MyDataRoot, Error>) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                
                let managedContext = self.appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext

                var count: Int = 0
                for d in response.data {
                           let newData = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "NewEntity", into: managedContext!)

                            newData.setValue("val1", forKey: "prop1")
                            newData.setValue("val2", forKey: "prop2")
                                                        
                                      do {
                                          try managedContext?.save()
                                         count += 1
                                      } catch {
                                          print("Error saving context: \(error)")
                                      }
                       
               }
        
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Failure: \(error)")
            }
        }.resume()
```

I also printed out the location of the db using the following:

```
#if os(iOS) && targetEnvironment(simulator)
        // New variable location for iOS Simulator Filesystem...
        if let last = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last {
            print("Documents Directory: \(last)")
        }
        #endif
```

Comment: What is `response.data`? Could it be that's empty? By the way, it's bad practice to save the context in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: response.data is coming back ok. it's not empty. I had the save outside the loop. This was more of my latest attempt at getting it to "work"

Comment: @PhillipMills In this case the code would crash in the insert line

Comment: How do you know it doesn't save anything?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I opened up the database and there are no records in the database table.

Comment: And you have double checked it is the right database? Sorry for this kind of questions but sometimes it's the simplest of mistakes that trips us.

Comment: I am expecting that it's something that has tripped me up. I think the code looks ok. I updated my question to include what I'm using to print out the db location.

Comment: Is Documents directory the right place to be looking?  I thought NSPersistentContainer defaulted to the Application Support library?

Comment: Edit your Scheme (Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme) and add the following Run argument `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1`. This will activate sqlite debugging and print the path to your db file in the console

Comment: thanks JoakimDanielson and pbasdf. You sent me on the right path. I was able to confirm with the run argument. appreciate the help!